# Match Ansible Keys to values of other keys within a nested dictionary

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have the following data structure

```
"my": {
    "topology": [
        {
            "management_topology": [
                {
                    "manager_id": "999999-abcd-1111-bbb-qwerty",
                    "switch": [
                        {
                            "dc_id": "datacenter-2",
                            "id": "1111111-aaa",
                            "server_node_id": [
                                "server1",
                                "server2"
                            ],
                            "switch_name": "mgmt-switch"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "random_attr_name": "new-mgmt-switch"
        },
        {
            "management_topology": [
                {
                    "manager_id": "999999-abcd-1111-bbb-qwerty",
                    "switch": [
                        {
                            "dc_id": "datacenter-2",
                            "id": "2222222-bbb",
                            "server_node_id": [
                                "server3",
                                "server4"
                            ],
                            "switch_name": "server-switch"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "random_attr_name": "new-server-switch"
        },
        {
            "management_topology": [
                {
                    "manager_id": "999999-abcd-1111-bbb-qwerty",
                    "switch": [
                        {
                            "dc_id": "datacenter-2",
                            "id": "3333333-ccc",
                            "server_node_id": [
                                "server5",
                                "server6"
                            ],
                            "switch_name": "dmz-switch"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "random_attr_name": "new-dmz-switch"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a list of dictionaries, pairing the value of *random_attr_name* with each value of *server_node_id*. That is

**EDIT** after commend from Larsk, i hadn't realised the issue of having duplicate Keys. Perhaps what i really need is the following dictionary of *server_node_id*: *random_attr_name*

```
"some_new_var": {
    "server1": "new-mgmt-switch",
    "server2": "new-mgmt-switch",
    "server3": "new-server-switch",
    "server4": "new-server-switch",
    "server5": "new-dmz-switch",
    "server6": "new-dmz-switch"
}
```

I've attempted the following to get this but, failed on each attempt

- items2dict `"{{ my.topology | items2dict( key_name='random_attr_name', value_name='management_topology.0.switch.0.server_node_id.values()' ) }}"`
- nested_dict
- subelements
- Jinja2 templating

Any guidance would be great. Think i'm over thinking/complicating this at this point

Comment: Your example `some_new_var` isn't a valid data structure. It's hard to tell what you want. You're using list delimiters (`[...]`) except the content looks like a dictionary...but you have duplicate keys, which would be problematic.

Comment: Thanks @larsks, your comment helped me think a bit more about this. I'm still not clear about how to do this but, hopefully my edit makes it a bit clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  # We're assuming your example data is contained
  # in the file "data.json".
  vars_files:
    data.json

  tasks:

    # In this task we create a YAML document that represents
    # the desired data structure.
    - set_fact:
        stage1: |
          {% for outer in my.topology %}
          {% for topo in outer.management_topology %}
          {% for switch in topo.switch %}
          {% for server in switch.server_node_id %}
          {{ server }}: {{ outer.random_attr_name }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

    # Now we de-serialize the YAML into a structured variable.
    - set_fact:
        server_map: "{{ stage1|from_yaml }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ server_map }}"
```

This results in:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "server1": "new-mgmt-switch",
        "server2": "new-mgmt-switch",
        "server3": "new-server-switch",
        "server4": "new-server-switch",
        "server5": "new-dmz-switch",
        "server6": "new-dmz-switch"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the dictionary of random names and server node ids

```yaml
  rname_ids: "{{ dict(my.topology|json_query(rname_ids_query)) }}"
  rname_ids_query: >
    [].[random_attr_name,
        management_topology[].switch[].server_node_id|[]]
```

gives

```yaml
  rname_ids:
    new-dmz-switch: [server5, server6]
    new-mgmt-switch: [server1, server2]
    new-server-switch: [server3, server4]
```

Unfold the dictionary

```yaml
  some_new_var: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for k,v in rname_ids.items() %}
    {% for i in v %}
    {{ k }}: {{ i }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  some_new_var:
    server1: new-mgmt-switch
    server2: new-mgmt-switch
    server3: new-server-switch
    server4: new-server-switch
    server5: new-dmz-switch
    server6: new-dmz-switch
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    data.json

  vars:

    rname_ids: "{{ dict(my.topology|json_query(rname_ids_query)) }}"
    rname_ids_query: >
      [].[random_attr_name,
          management_topology[].switch[].server_node_id|[]]

    some_new_var: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k,v in rname_ids.items() %}
      {% for i in v %}
      {{ k }}: {{ i }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: rname_ids
    - debug:
        var: some_new_var
```